Kubuntu 24.04 Black Screen / Not Booting After Upgrade
I suspect this will be along similar lines to other folks, but in reading numerous posts I cannot find any that are really similar to my issues.
History...
Perfectly working Kubuntu system, no issues ever since original build.
An alert pops up offering an upgrade to Kubuntu 24.04, so I think why not upgrade... wish I hadn't now.
Perform upgrade, all appears well afterwards.
Days after upgrade, turn on computer... motherboard logo shows, then system goes to a black screen.
Pressing Del during post allows me to go into BIOS... no issues found in BIOS, original NVME drive listed as primary boot.
Pressing ESC during post allows me to get to grub> but I am not a grub guru so unsure what to do there?
Inserting a USB drive allows booting into Kubuntu Live CD, all works well, full graphics, and can see data on original NVME drive that wont boot.
During inserting USB drives and pressing reset button somehow the original drive boots (no idea why)... performed sudo apt update / upgrade - rebooted machine, and get a black screen.
Since the above I can no longer get original system to boot, just the usual black screen. Further diagnostic suggestions appreciated.

I've got the exact same issue, and the same sequence on how I got there with the 24.04 upgrade. Totally hosed.

Yeah, it's painful... here's something I found that has completely thrown me... when the PC posts and I press F12 to choose a boot source, and then choose the drive option that has Kubuntu loaded on it... it boots?? Yet, if I just power it on, black screen... really weird.

There's one difference. I can't get it to boot at all. Even a one-time boot menu doesn't allow me to get into the system.

I rebooted again without dock or power, and it came up this time... and is still behaving after plugging in the dock. No idea why. I didn't change anything aside from pulling the plug again. My trust level is not high right now...

This isn't a full solution, but a workaround that will give you back functionality. This issue seems to be affecting a number of distros at the moment so I imagine it'll be patched soon. I found the instructions on reddit here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Kubuntu/comments/1cdko49/comment/l1ht1l9/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button

Access the Grub menu by holding down right shift while your computer is booting.
Boot Kubuntu in recovery mode (you may have to look in a sub-menu).
Once booted, run sudo nano /etc/default/grub.
Edit the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='quiet splash' to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='quiet' and save your changes.
Run sudo update-grub and reboot.


Thank you for the advice. It appears to have worked and the system is consistently booting... for the time being. Be interested to know what caused the issue? As you say, there appears to be a number of folk impacted. Thanks again.

@GregoInc The cause is mentioned in the comments at the linked page: "The GPU drivers aren't loaded so calling a picture causes the system to crash. Waiting another second or two (no-splash) allows the system time to load the GPU drivers and work properly."

Solved my problem as well. Later had GPU drivers and activated splash after @AlexeiKhlebnikov 's comment and works fine now.

The workaround I found before this was to boot in recovery mode and then just resume a normal boot. This allowed the system to boot normally after this point.

having the same issue, what's working for me is in grub chosing aditional options for ubuntu then chosing the kernel 6.8.0-40-generic instead of 6.8.0-41-generic, hope this helps :)
edit: Dáire O Carroll's solution worked, also edited my answer with the full kernel names

It might help if you had actually given complete kernel versions. As written is of no help at all.

@DavidDE did as requested, hope it helps :)
